# Automatic conversion of data from your sample

Tags: angular

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){
    this.test()
  }
  data:any=[1,2,3,4,5]
  test(){
    const a=this.data;
    a.splice(0,1);
    console.log('a= ' +a);
    console.log('data= '+this.data)
  }
}
```

console:

```
 a= 2,3,4,5
 data= 2,3,4,5
```

I just want the variable a to change but it changes to both !!!!! How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thats because JavaScript copies arrays by reference and not value.

In your case you can clone the original array and modify it by doing something like:

```
const a = [...this.data]
```

Then applying any transformations to `a` will not affect the original `data` array.

Extra reading: https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/35-es6-way-to-clone-an-array/

Answer (score 0):

Deep copy of the array `this.data.forEach(value => a.push(value);`

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){
    this.test()
  }
  data:any=[1,2,3,4,5]
  test(){
    const a = []
    this.data.forEach(value => a.push(value);
    a.splice(0,1);
    console.log('a= ' +a);
    console.log('data= '+this.data)
  }
}
```